# I have 2 documents, how can I write a query which return output as single document

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Document 1
{
  "accountId": "Test",
  "documentType": "config1",
  "name": "TestName",
  "url": "http://foo"
  "date": "2015-08-26T20:27:10.7204029Z"
}

Document 2
{
  "accountId": "Test",
  "documentType": "config2",
  "area": "testArea",
}

Expected output as single document:
{
  "accountId": "Test",
  "documentType": "config",
  "name": "TestName",
  "area": "testArea"
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, you can't. 
They are two documents. You can't JOIN two independent units together.

You can have a single document with embedded entities, then it is a single document with two sub-documents and you could potentially do something like this.

So maybe have {"accountId" : "Test", "config" : [ {"id": "config1", "" }, {"id" : "config2" } ] }

Comment: I cannot merge them, as one document is static and another is very rapidly updated. That is why I have 2 different documents. But I need result to merged together for UI to show information. Now, I need to provide list of 2 documents to UI. I can work with that. Thanks!!

Comment: glad to hear you have a workable solution. please mark question as answered.